# Argument is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: rxjs, flatmap

I'm new to rxjs, i read the docs but still i have a problem with my code.

I'm trying the code below:

```
    ​let​ friends= [{
        name: ​'Jill'​,
        favoriteFoods: [​'pizza'​, ​'hummus'​]
    }, {
        name: ​'Bob'​,
        favoriteFoods: [​'ice cream'​]
    }, {
        name: ​'Alice'​,
        favoriteFoods: [​'chicken wings'​, ​'salmon'​]
    }];
        ​    ​ 
    flatMap(friends, friend => friend.favoriteFoods);
```

In Visual Studio Code in the flatMap line on "friends" i have the error
"Argument of type '{ name: string; favoriteFoods: string[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
  Type '{ name: string; favoriteFoods: string[]; }[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: unknown, index: number): ObservableInput'"

The sample is from this book https://pragprog.com/titles/rkrxjs/source_code probably there is some new version of typescript than the one used in the book.
I would understand what is the correct code.

Comment: Could you explain, what are you trying to do? If you just want to transform the array, you shouldn't use rxjs for that: `friends.map(friend => friend.favoriteFoods)`. RxJs is about streams of data, but you work with a data in the example.

Comment: Sorry for the very long delay, I was busy in other activities.
The book uses RxJs for this transformation and is given for working: perhaps the best thing is to contact the book author.